# How to set locale default_url_options for functional tests (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, internationalization

In my application_controller, I have the following set to include the locale with all paths generated by url_for:

```
  def default_url_options(options={})
    { :locale => I18n.locale }
  end
```

My resource routes then have a :path_prefix = "/:locale"

Works fine on the site.

But when it comes to my functional tests, the :locale is not passed with the generated urls, and therefore they all fail. I can get around it by adding the locale to the url in my tests, like so:

```
  get :new, :locale => 'en'
```

But I don't want to have to manually add the locale to every functional test.

I tried adding the default_url_options def above to test_helper, but it seems to have no effect.

Is there any way I can change the default_url_options to include the locale for all my tests?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking through how the controller test case generates the url there doesn't seem to be a direct way to have it use the defualt_url_options. The main block that actually does the url creationg (in the tests) looks like this (http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb):

```
private
  def build_request_uri(action, parameters)
    unless @request.env['REQUEST_URI']
      options = @controller.__send__(:rewrite_options, parameters)
      options.update(:only_path => true, :action => action)

      url = ActionController::UrlRewriter.new(@request, parameters)
      @request.request_uri = url.rewrite(options)
    end
  end
```

This gets called by the process method which is in turn called by the get, post, head, or put methods. One way to maybe get what you are looking for might be to alias_chain the process method.

```
class ActionController::TestCase
  def process_with_default_locale(action, parameters = nil, session = nil, flash = nil, http_method = 'GET')
    parameters = {:locale=>'en'}.merge(parameters||{})
    process_without_default_locale(action, parameters, session, flash, http_method)
  end
  alias_method_chain :process, :default_locale
end
```

You'll want to put that into your test helper, outside of the TestCase class I think. Let me know how it works for you, I haven't really tested it out so we'll see.

Comment: Thanks, John. That solved the specific case above and seems to work great!

What it doesn't seem to solve is how TestCase interprets named routes, whether they're in the test itself, or used in the application. For example, if I have in a test:

redirect_to homepage_url

and homepath_url expects the locale (map.homepage '/:locale', :controller => 'home'), I get an error, when running the test, that the url requirements are not satisfield (missing "locale"). Again, the application runs fine as default_url_options takes care of adding the locale. Any way to fix that?

Comment: Let me add that if this was only a problem in the test themselves, it wouldn't be so bad. I can just add the locale whenever used a named route in a test. But the problem is that it also generates an error whenever a named route is used in my application (and I don't want to have to change all that or specify the locale each time just so my tests will run).

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize it was happening in your app as well. I just came across a lighthouse ticket that might help you out a little bit (seems to still be an issue but there are some work arounds) https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/1251-default_url_options-cant-be-used-with-named-routes

Comment: Other than that it's beyond me, might be worthwhile to ask another question specifically about the named routes and default_url_options not working in the app and see if anyone has any ideas.

Answer (score 8):

For Rails 5, I found this simple solution
In `test_helper.rb` based on [action_dispatch/testing/integration.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/testing/integration.rb#L408-L410)

```
module ActionDispatch::Integration
  class Session
    def default_url_options
      { locale: I18n.locale }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it worked for me. Although I was wondering if there is any way to use a customize default_url_options from the ApplicationController, because it doesn't make any sense to write twice the same configuration.

Comment: I would just add than maybe it's better to use the options as defined in `ApplicationController`, for consistence:

`ApplicationController.new.send(:default_url_options)`

Answer (score 7):

In the Rails 3.1-stable branch, the [process method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-1-stable/actionpack/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb#L411) is now within a `Behavior` module. So here is the code which worked for me (slightly different from John Duff's answer):

```
class ActionController::TestCase

  module Behavior
    def process_with_default_locale(action, parameters = nil, session = nil, flash = nil, http_method = 'GET')
      parameters = { :locale => I18n.default_locale }.merge( parameters || {} )
      process_without_default_locale(action, parameters, session, flash, http_method)
    end 
    alias_method_chain :process, :default_locale
  end 
end
```

And I made sure this code gets called before running the specs/tests. A good place to put it is in the test_helper class.

Comment: Martin Carel lays out this method on http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/3448797 he also adds another method: `module ActionDispatch::Assertions::RoutingAssertions
  def assert_recognizes_with_default_locale(expected_options, path,
extras={}, message=nil)
    expected_options = { :locale => I18n.default_locale.to_s
}.merge(expected_options || {} )
    assert_recognizes_without_default_locale(expected_options, path,
extras, message)
  end
  alias_method_chain :assert_recognizes, :default_locale
end`

Comment: I also said that modifying the `assert_recognizes` method was a **cheat**. Indeed, I don't think it's a good idea to hack your testing tools like that, as opposed to mock the code you're trying to test (as is the case with adding a method to the `Behavior` module).

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone is using this with Rails 4.0, the order of arguments in the [`process`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d625a7ac1746431b37a5a0b064409b909efde632/actionpack/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb#L417) method has changed, so you'll need to use this updated patch (based on @martin-carel's answer, just with the `http_method` argument moved to the second argument):

```
class ActionController::TestCase
  module Behavior
    def process_with_default_locale(action, http_method = 'GET', parameters = nil, session = nil, flash = nil)
      parameters = { :locale => I18n.locale }.merge( parameters || {} ) unless I18n.locale.nil?
      process_without_default_locale(action, http_method, parameters, session, flash)
    end
    alias_method_chain :process, :default_locale
  end
end
```

Hope that helps anyone stuck on this problem.

Answer (score 3):

I tried a lot of examples, but only this one helped me. It is concise and simple. Add this code snippet to the test.rb:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # ... other config ...

  routes.default_url_options[:locale] = :en
end
```

Works on Rails 5.1.4

Comment: Can confirm that this works on Rails 6.0.0 as well.

Comment: Worked for me as well with Rails 6, I put it into `test_helper.rb` inside the `ActiveSupport::TestCase` class.

Answer (score 2):

`alias_method_chain` is [deprecated in Rails 5](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2015/3/27/this-week-in-rails-goodbye-alias_method_chain-postgresql-typecasting-and-more/), and it seems the Behavior process method has changed.

Here's my modification of Martin Carel's answer above, adapted to Rails 5.

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  module ActionController
    class TestCase
      module Behavior
        module LocaleParameter
          def process(action, parameters = {params: {}})
            unless I18n.locale.nil?
              parameters[:params][:locale] = I18n.locale
            end

            super(action, parameters)
          end
        end

        prepend Behavior::LocaleParameter

      end
    end
  end
end
```

I'm by no means an expert in Rails or Ruby, so if something can be improved in this answer, let me know and I'll change it.

Comment: Yes!! this is the solution, and  adding to each Test I want to define a different locale  `before :context do  I18n.locale = :ca end` I can test whatever locale I need for each circunstance. Using rails 5.1.4.rc1

Comment: I added  `if parameters[:params].nil? parameters[:params]={} end` before `unless I18n.locale.nil?....` to avoid crash for request without parameters

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem with a failing cucumber test.
I use locales as parameters in the url, i.e. http://mysite.com/home?locale=he

What I do to cope with this is to drop all locale related stuff from the url during testing by defining default_url_options depending on the environment I use:

```
  # app/controllers/application_controller.rb
  def default_url_options(options={})
    logger.debug "default_url_options is passed options: #{options.inspect}\n"
    ENV["RAILS_ENV"] != "cucumber" ? { :locale => I18n.locale } : {}
  end
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this exposes certain edge cases, but it seems like an otherwise elegant solution to me.

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with a bit less invasive solution to this problem.

```
setup :set_default_locale 

def set_default_locale
  def @request.query_parameters
    {:locale => "en"}.merge(@query_parameters)
  end
end
```

The advantage of this solution is that it means you can only apply the default locale parameter to certain test cases, so you can test, for example, the redirection strategy itself.

Answer (score 1):

Things changed again with Ruby 5.1. Here's what worked for me:

```
class ActionController::TestCase
  module Behavior
    module LocaleParameter
      def process(action, params: {}, **args)
        # Locale parameter must be a string
        params[:locale] = I18n.locale.to_s
        super(action, params: params, **args)
      end
    end
  end
  prepend Behavior::LocaleParameter
end
```

Answer (score 0):

With integration testing, I found that the above monkey patch needs to be different, this is what worked for me (Rails 2.3.4):

```
class ActionController::Integration::Session
  def url_for_with_default_locale(options)
    options = { :locale => 'en' }.merge(options)
    url_for_without_default_locale(options)
  end
  alias_method_chain :url_for, :default_locale
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`default_url_options` are not used when processing functional tests and it doesn't seem there is a way to define defaults without monkey patching ([master branch from October 15th 2021](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/dcae1281b7c6de92da879909e4bc3c4b08a3fa86/actionpack/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb#L467-L504)).

So I managed to get it working by overwriting the `ActionController::TestCase#process` method within the `test/test_helper.rb` file as follows:

```
class ActionController::TestCase
  module DefaultParameters
    def process(action, params: {}, **args)
      params[:locale] ||= 'en'
      super(action, params: params, **args)
    end
  end
  prepend DefaultParameters
end
```

The above code works with Rails 6.1.4 but might need some adjustments for earlier or future Rails versions.