# Setting default_url_options in test environment doesn't seem to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec

I've put the following code into my `config/environments/test.rb` file:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "localhost:3000" }
```

however when I run my tests, all routes use `http://test.host`. I'm trying to work with an API that won't accept `http://test.host` as a valid callback URI, so I need to change this to properly receive the API response. Any idea why this isn't working? (I'm using RSpec, Guard, and Spork in my testing suite).

**EDIT**: Possibly relevant - this is being done inside of a controller spec.

**EDIT2**: It seems that it changes after a request is made via `get`, `post`, etc. Running the following code within the test:

```
Rails.logger.debug users_url
get 'http://google.com'
Rails.logger.debug users_url
```

would produce the following output:

```
http://localhost:3000/users
...get request related response here
http://google.com/users
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Nowadays you can just set them in your `test.rb` like so:

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host]= 'localhost:3000'
```

Answer (score 13):

`Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host]= 'localhost:3000'`

In the developemnt.rb / test.rb, can be more concise as following:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # ... other config ...

  routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'localhost:3000'
end
```

Comment: Works in Rails 5.1.4. Saved me a lot of time.

Comment: I was having an issue with my specs after setting `default_url_options` for locale in my app controller. This fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, `url_options` will not be passed into tests without a bit of hacking.

See e.g.

- [How to set locale default_url_options for functional tests (Rails)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987354/how-to-set-locale-default-url-options-for-functional-tests-rails)
- http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/3448797

I've frequently encountered this problem when trying to set the locale in tests. I've never used action mailer, though, so there may be a simpler way to do it.

The solution I've found for setting the default locale in `url_options` is just to [patch actiondispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414400/basic-devise-spec-with-i18n) and force it to use whatever locale I want it to. You could adapt this to your case this way:

```
class ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet
  def url_for_with_default_url_options(options)
    url_for_without_default_url_options(options.merge(:host => "localhost:3000" ))
  end

  alias_method_chain :url_for, :default_url_options
end
```

I put that code in a file in spec/support so it is used in rspec tests and I also require it from my env.rb file so I can use it in cucumber tests as well.

Keep in mind that this will patch it *everywhere*, in both test code and in actual code running under tests, and it will override any other settings for the `:host` key that you try to pass in (since the patch merges the fix on top of the options passed into `url_for`). In your case I believe that shouldn't be a problem.

Monkey patching is not a very elegant solution, though, and I used this after everything else failed. You might find a simpler solution specific to action mailer.

Answer (score -1):

How are you running your tests? Maybe appending `RAILS_ENV=test` might help.

Comment: What do you mean by appending `RAILS_ENV=test`? `ENV["RAILS_ENV"]` is `"test"` already. As mentioned, I'm running the tests with RSpec, Guard, and Spork. I just run `bundle exec guard` and it loads up the Spork server, which automatically runs the RSpec tests.