# Why selenium is throwing Net::Read::Timeout error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, watir

Selenium is throwing net read time out error on random statements. I am unable to find out this is because of issue in proxy or selenium is throwing this exception due to another reason?
I am attaching a backtrace below.

```
Net::readtimeout with #<tcpsocket:(closed)>

/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/protocol.rb:217:in `rbuf_fill'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/protocol.rb:191:in `readuntil'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/protocol.rb:201:in `readline'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/http/response.rb:42:in `read_status_line'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/http/response.rb:31:in `read_new'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/http.rb:1528:in `block in transport_request'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/http.rb:1519:in `catch'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/http.rb:1519:in `transport_request'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/http.rb:1492:in `request'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:129:in `response_for'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:82:in `request'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:64:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:167:in `execute'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c/bridge.rb:567:in `execute'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c/bridge.rb:59:in `get'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/navigation.rb:32:in `to'
/var/www/bce-parser/bluecare_express_service.rb:121:in `block (3 levels) in parse_new_orders'
/var/www/bce-parser/bluecare_express_service.rb:118:in `each'
/var/www/bce-parser/bluecare_express_service.rb:118:in `block (2 levels) in parse_new_orders'
/var/www/bce-parser/bluecare_express_service.rb:101:in `each'
/var/www/bce-parser/bluecare_express_service.rb:101:in `block in parse_new_orders'
/var/www/bce-parser/bluecare_express_service.rb:82:in `loop'
/var/www/bce-parser/bluecare_express_service.rb:82:in `parse_new_orders'
/var/www/bce-parser/bluecare_express_service.rb:61:in `call'
run_parser.rb:8:in `<main>'
```

Statement on which this exception occurs `@driver.navigate.to(tracking_page_url)`

Comment: Can you share the `tracking_page_url` value for which this exception is raising? Does it "randomly" work with some of them and not with others? Or does it always fail with the same ones?

Comment: Thanks benj-p. Yeah it **randomly** works with some of them. It was a proxy issue, proxy server was not responding in given time frame

Answer (score 0):

You have to increase the page load time out, it waits default time of 60 seconds but you can increase the page load timeout by the following code

```
client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
client.read_timeout = 120 # seconds
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome,http_client: client
```

Now your code would wait for 120 seconds for any page load which has been caused by #click and also wait to load the url by goto method.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this already this has not fixed the issue.

Comment: What's your selenium version?

Comment: Selenium version: 3.142
Chrome version: 88

Answer (score 0):

#### Changed _url => _path

I got the exception on during a Rails system test when I did a visit to `root_url` but it was fine with `root_path`

[I set the default_url in the test environment to localhost:3000 but didn't change anything for me.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13004522/setting-default-url-options-in-test-environment-doesnt-seem-to-work)