# How to set locale in default url options for integration tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing, ruby-on-rails-4

Using Rails 4.0.0beta1, i'm trying to create some integration tests.
All my URLs are scoped with me `locale` (e.g. `/en/user/new`) and i'm having the following error each time i try to call `new_user_url` :

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"user"} missing required keys: [:locale]
```

I've tried the solution given by @Balint Erdi in the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2565277/1872168)

```rb
class ActionController::Integration::Session
  def url_for_with_default_locale(options)
    options = { locale: I18n.locale }.merge(options)
    url_for_without_default_locale(options)
  end

  alias_method_chain :url_for, :default_locale
end
```

It works but gives me a deprecation warning because of rails4:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActionController::Integration is deprecated and will be removed, use ActionDispatch::Integration instead. (called from <top (required)> at /path/to/project/test/test_helper.rb:46)
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActionController::IntegrationTest is deprecated and will be removed, use ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest instead. (called from <top (required)> at /path/to/project/test/test_helper.rb:46)
```

For my controller tests i added this :

```rb
class ActionController::TestCase

  module Behavior
    def process_with_default_locale(action, http_method = 'GET', parameters = nil, session = nil, flash = nil)
      parameters = { locale: I18n.locale }.merge( parameters || {} ) 
      process_without_default_locale(action, http_method, parameters, session, flash)
    end

    alias_method_chain :process, :default_locale
  end 
end
```

I've also tested adding a `default_url_options` method directly into the tests but it did not work.

How can i set the default url parameters in integration tests ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it seems it's as easy as replacing `ActionController` by `ActionDispatch`. I don't know why it didn't work before but since I updated to the latest rails which deprecates `rake test:integration` for `rails test integration` it seems to work:

```rb
class ActionDispatch::Integration::Session
  def url_for_with_default_locale(options)
    options = { locale: I18n.locale }.merge(options)
    url_for_without_default_locale(options)
  end

  alias_method_chain :url_for, :default_locale
end
```

Answer (score 5):

An option that worked for me (at least in Rails 4.2.0) was to add a setup method to the `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` class in my `test/test_helper.rb`:

```
class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  def setup
    self.default_url_options = { locale: I18n.default_locale }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails 5, Minitest example:

```
class SomeTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup do
    self.default_url_options = { locale: I18n.default_locale }
  end

  def test_something
    ...
  end
end
```